# Groovy Closure reuse vs rehydrate copy

Tags: groovy, dsl, groovydsl

In the [DSL page of groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html) they show this

```
def email(Closure cl) {
  def email = new EmailSpec()
  def code = cl.rehydrate(email, this, this)
  code.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
  code()
}
```

Why are they calling `rehydrate` instead of just assigning the delegate to the closure:

```
def email(Closure cl) {
  def email = new EmailSpec()
  cl.delegate = email
  cl.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
  cl()
}
```

In other words, why do we need a copy of the closure instead of reusing the one given. I don't necessarily see a problem with using rehydrate but I also don't see the need, which tells me there's something I'm not understanding

Comment: `rehydrate` doesn't just set the delegate

Comment: @tim_yates I know, it creates a clone. My question is more why does the doc recommend a clone instead of reusing the same object and avoid creating a new object. There must be a reason

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it returns a copy rather than reusing the same closure in order to stay idempotent/safe in case you still need a reference to the old closure.

As @tim_yates mentioned, the [`rehydrate`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#rehydrate(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) method sets the `delegate`, `owner`, and `thisObject`, whereas your second example only sets the `delegate`. It's not that the `rehydrate` method does anything magical, it's just a convenience method so you don't have to set all three properties individually/line-by-line.

I also believe `rehydrate` is meant to work with its partner method [`dehydrate`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#dehydrate()), which returns a copy of the closure with those three fields cleared (allowing `rehydrate` to easily re-set them).